# jQuery Heatmap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, html, heatmap

I've been looking for a while for a jQuery or JavaScript heatmap that looks close to this:

[image: http://www.activetick.com/activetick/contents/images/PlatformLatestChanges/HeatmapMarketCap.png]

Infovis has a Treemap, but those borders within each box is annoying/not what I'm looking for.
I'd prefer to stick with a language that I'm familiar with, javascript, jQuery, Perl, but willing to expand if the solution is out there.

Note: I've been told "R" language can do this, but this might be overkill for the dataset I have. Example dataset could be States for each box, size based on population, and color based on unemployment rate (not to be too dramatic).

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That's actually a [TreeMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this example from the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit ( http://thejit.org/ )?
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.html

Comment: "Infovis has a Treemap, but those borders within each box is annoying/not what I'm looking for."

Comment: Well, I caved and this is what I went for :) The other options were good and acceptable, but required a bit more time than I could dedicate to get the project underway. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Try Google Chart Tools: [Start page](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), [Treemap](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap.html)